# An ordered pair not belonging to a Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do we expand the following statement.
Consider $r=(m,n)$ to be an ordered pair.

Let $C$ and $D$ be any two sets so that,
$r$ does not belong to the Cartesian product $C \times D$.

How do we expand this in mathematical notation?
(Specifically statement about $m$ and $n$ belonging to $C$ and $D$.)

Comment: $r=(m,n) \notin C \times D$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I meant further expansion. Is it required that both m and n should not belong to C and D respectively? Or is it enough that one of them do not belong?

Comment: ($m$ not in $C$) or ($n$ not in $D$).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! I was struggling with an and operator and getting three different conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$C \times D = \{(m,n) \mid m \in C \text{ and } n \in D \}$$
Thus $(m,n) \notin C \times D$ means $m \notin C$ or $n \notin D$.

Comment: @GerryMerson I was typing my answer while you wrote your comment...

Comment: Thank you! Converting the operation to and, we do get three different conditions, right?

Comment: No worries, J.-E.